# How to delete nodes from XML with exact string match in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have below xml. I want to delete those nodes which doesn't contains attributes. in below xml I want to delete last 4 nodes which doesn't have attributes.

**XML**

```
<products>
    <product system="kn-movies" code="UR">Unrated</product>
    <product system="mu-movies" code="UR">Unrated</product>
    <product system="na-movies" code="UR">Unrated</product>
    <product system="fj-movies" code="UR">Unrated</product>
    <product>Unrated (Unrated )</product>
    <product>Unrated (Unrated )</product>
    <product>Unrated (Без классификации )</product>
    <product>Unrated (غير مصنف )</product>
</products>
```

I had tried this c# code

```
var ratingNode = document.Descendants("rating").Where(t => t != null && t.Equals(Convert.ToString(nodeItem))).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (ratingNode != null)
                            {
                                ratingNode.Remove();
                            }
```

but it doesn't worked for me. please help me out where i m doing mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(filepath);
var newList = doc.Root.Descendants().ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Attributes() == null || x.Attributes().Count() <= 0);
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will do trick

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("products");
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if(node.Attributes.Count == 0)
    {
        node.RemoveAll;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Linq` to `Xml` and query for elements which has no attributes, then you just need `Remove` call to remove those elements.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);       
doc.Root
   .Descendants()                             // flattens the structure 
   .Where(x=> x.Attributes().Count() <= 0)     // filter elements which has no attributes
   .Remove();                                 // Remove them
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fvbnuw)